# Jquery Table with JQGrid can't show the information

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a very curious bug or error with JQuery with JqGrid. The error is when I try to show the data in JSON in the table, if you show me the data, if the table does not show more than 20 columns and have more than 200 data, the code is presented like this:

The Header is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<!-- Continuacion de JqGrid-->
<!-- A link to a jQuery UI ThemeRoller theme, more than 22 built-in and many more custom -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- The link to the CSS that the grid needs -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" />
```

The JS is:

```
<script>
    $.jgrid.defaults.width = 780;
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<div style="margin-left:20px">
    <table id="jqGrid4"></table>
    <div id="jqGridPager4"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#jqGrid4").jqGrid({
            url: 'http://localhost/fileupload/api/Proveedor',
            mtype: "GET",
            styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
            datatype: "JSON",
            colModel: [
                { label: 'id', name: 'id', key: true, width: 75 },
                { label: 'Name', name: 'Name', width: 150 },
                { label: 'RFC', name: 'RFC', width: 150 },
                { label: 'Company Name', name: 'CompanyName', width: 150 },
                { label:'DateCreation', name: 'DateCreation', width: 150 }
            ],
            viewrecords: true,
            height: 250,
            rowNum: 20,
            pager: "#jqGridPager4",
            sortable: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

[image: table]

In the image you can see that the table only shows 20 rows, but I have 207 rows.  I need the arrows to move and show more rows, but I can't. Any ideas? I don't want to put rowNum: +20 or more because I don't like that, I need to move with the arrows but I can't.

Comment: How looks the response from `/fileupload/api/Proveedor`? Do you implemented *server-side paging* on the server or the server returnes all 207 rows at once and you want to use *client-side paging*? In the last case you should add `loadonce: true` option.

Comment: THIS IS !!!!!! @Oleg thanks so much !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you implemented *server-side paging* on the server or the server returnes all 207 rows at once and you want to use *client-side paging*? In the last case you should add `loadonce: true` option. 207 rows is not much and thus I would recommend you to use `loadonce: true` option in the scenario. You will don't need to write long code on the server side and can directly use sorting, paging and filtering/searching (see [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) or [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching)) of *local* data.